# Postgis 4D Range Query

Tags: postgis

Is it possible to express a 4D range query in Postgis? I would like to know what 4d points lie within a hypercube.
This is my table:

```
    CREATE TABLE myTable
    (
      point geometry,
      attrib double precision,
      CONSTRAINT ge_idx PRIMARY KEY (point)
    );
```

This is how I inserted the data points:

```
    insert into myTable (point) values (ST_MakePoint(-71.10, 42.31, 12.43, 54.3));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the &&& operator for a hypercube query. Since like its brother && it is a bounding box query, you just need to create a query geometry that spans the desired cube: a linestring is the easiest to make:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE point &&& 'LINESTRING(50 50 50 50, 100 100 100 100)';
```